# How to get time irrelevant to timezone

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a app where I issue hashes that is partly based on a timestamp. But how can I on the client side get time that is irrelevant to the users timezone as the client and server not in the same timezone most probably?

Comment: Look Jon skeet has answered your question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx). That will still be based on the local system clock though - if you need this in any sort of security context, you quite possibly don't want to trust the user's clock, and should only trust timestamps on the server. It depends on your requirements, really.

Note that if you're *formatting* the result of `DateTime.UtcNow` (e.g. for communication), you should then format it in the invariant culture. Even if you specify a custom format, if the user's culture is one which uses a different calendar (e.g. the Islamic calendar) you'll end up with different results.

Alternatively, as you *just* want a timestamp, use [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) (on the result of calling `DateTime.UtcNow`, of course). It sounds like you don't really care about any human notion of months, years, time of day etc - you just want an arbitrary value measuring time, which is what `Ticks` gets you.

Comment: Upvote if helped , not because its Jon Skeet. Hope you don't mind Jon.

Answer (score 4):

Use [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) for your purpose.

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).